# Why $\frac{\partial}{\partial W} tr[WHH^TW^T] = 2WHH^T$

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus

I recently started studying matrix calculus and in some notes on matrix factorization, I came across this:
[Click here to see the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdaU6.png)
(Properties (9) and (12) from the screenshot are the properties 101 and 102 from the Matrix Cookbook (see link below), but I don't think they are relevant with the part I'm stuck in )

I **Can't understand why the derivative of
$tr[WHH^TW^T]$ is $2WHH^T$**
I am working with the theory and properties from [The Matrix Cookbook](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ehwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf) and I can't figure it out.
The properties listed on page 13 of the cookbook seem to be the suitable ones but they don't return the wanted result, so I am probably missing something important.

Thanks a lot to everyone who took time to read it, 
Have a nice day and stay safe!

Comment: Using the derivative of the product, and the property that $tr(A+B)=tr(A)+tr(B)$ should work out I guess; see that you have $tr(AA^{T})$, with $A=WH$

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I didn't really understand what you mean, can please you explain your idea a bit more?

Comment: Maybe you can use $\partial_{W}tr(WHH^{T}W^{T})=(HH^{T}W^{T})^{T} + WHH^{T}$ by virtue of the derivative of a product and the rule 100 of the book (in fact, you might want to take rule 100 and apply it to the transpose case).

Comment: Following your advise (Before you edited the second comment), I reached this form: $tr(WHH^T) + tr(WHH^T)$, which is very close to the result but I still don't know how to "remove" the trace while staying on a closed type solution now that it's not a derivative. Sorry if the question is trivial but I have some knowledge gaps on this subject that I'm working on filling. I will try the edited idea now it looks really promising

Comment: Yes the previous, deleted comment was not entirely correct, given that I didn't make use of the derivative of traces at all, and just made $\partial_{W}tr=tr\partial_{W}$, which I suspect is not allowed in the cases you are considering. As I suggested on the second comment, try using eq.(100) both as in the book, and with the transpose version of it, and it should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, I actually struggled to solve it because of a trivial mistake early on between calculations... Anyway, I believe I now have a much better understanding of matrix factorization in general. thanks again for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def\p#1#2{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}$It
is convenient to replace the trace function with a product notation, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= {\rm Tr}(AB^T) \;=\; \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{i=j}^n A_{ij} B_{ij} \\
A:A &= \big\|A\big\|^2_F \\
}$$
When $(A,B)$ are vectors the colon product corresponds to the ordinary dot product.

The properties of the underlying trace allow the terms in such a product to be rearranged in a number of equivalent ways, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= B:A = B^T:A^T \\
CA:B &= C:BA^T = A:C^TB \\
}$$
${\bf NB}\!:\;$ The matrix on each side of the colon has the **same** dimensions.

This product simplifies the calculation of gradients.

For example, the gradient of a linear function is
$$\eqalign{
\lambda &= {\rm Tr}(LY^T) \\&= L:Y \\
d\lambda &= L:dY \\
\p{\lambda}{Y} &= L \\
}$$
while that of a quadratic function is
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= {\rm Tr}(YQY^T) \\&= YQ:Y \\
d\phi &= dY\,Q:Y + YQ:dY \\
 &= YQ^T:dY + YQ:dY \\
 &= Y\left(Q+Q^T\right):dY \\
\p{\phi}{Y} &= Y\left(Q+Q^T\right) \\\\
}$$
To apply this to the function in question,
set  $\,Q=HH^T,\,Y=W\,$ to obtain
$$\eqalign{
d\left(WHH^T:W\right) &= 2WHH^T:dW \\
\p{\left(WHH^T:W\right)}{W} &= 2WHH^T \\
}$$
For the function in the linked image,
setting  $\,Q=I,\,Y=(WH-X)\,$ yields
$$\eqalign{
d\left(Y:Y\right) &= (2I)Y:dY = 2Y:dW\,H = 2YH^T:dW \\
\p{(Y:Y)}{W} &= 2YH^T \;=\; 2(WH-X)H^T \\
}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to write an analytical answer, I actually haven't realized the connection between dot product and traces since I read your answer. You sure helped fill some gaps in my knowledge! Thanks again and stay safe!